# Resize image with Imagemagick in node

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

I was working on imagemagick module in nodejs, and I'm stuck at some point. I'm trying to resize my image. I need base64 part of the resized image. How can I retrieve it? I tried below code but this one creates empty image.

```
 im.resize({
        srcPath: image,
        width: 750,
        height: 280
      }, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        console.log('resized store-medium.jpg to fit within 750x280px');
        var mediumImage = new Buffer(stdout).toString('base64');
```

Comment: This is a rather old topic, but since I have the same issue, i'll give it a try. @ahmet-tanakol: did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: @RicardoPesciotta unfortunately I couldn't find a proper solution and I used  a service called imgix https://www.imgix.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dstPath` parameter and read resulting image and then convert to Base64.

Example:

```
var dstImage = image.replace(/\.\w+$/, '-resized.');
im.resize({
    srcPath: image,
    dstPath: dstImage, // <--- destiny image
    width: 750,
    height: 280
}, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
    console.log('resized store-medium.jpg to fit within 750x280px');
    fs.readFile(dstImage, function (err, data) {
        next(null, data.toString('base64'));
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm going to resize and upload a lot of images so this method will create too many copies.